# Will scaling down RDS instance preserve data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have Amazon Aurora for `MySQL t3.db.medium instances`. I would like to `scale down to t3.db.small`.

If I modify the instance settings in AWS console, **will my DB data be preserved? So can I scale down without service interruption?** I think I should be able to do this, but I just wanna make sure. There is prod instance involved.

I have the same question about Elastic Cache (AWS redis). Can I scale that down without service interruption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Modifying.html#Aurora.Modifying.Settings), there is table(**DB instance class**) which tells which settings can be changed, you can change your instance class for your aurora, **as a note An outage occurs during this change.**

> For redis

according to [docs](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/redis-cluster-vertical-scaling.html), you can scale down node type of your redis cluster (version 3.2 or newer). During scale down ElastiCache dynamically resizes your cluster while remaining online and serving requests.

In both the cases your data will be preserved.